# Performance difference when running app in iPhone simulator from XCode and when starting in Simulator directly

Tags: iphone, xcode, performance

I have some strange performance differences when I run an iPhone application on the simulator a) from XCode and b) directly in the simulator.

One method which calculates some stats from all objects in my Core Data DB takes less then one second when I run it directly in the simulator and it takes 22 seconds when I start the application on the simulator from XCode (no breakpoints and not debugging).

How is that possible? Yes the method gets all elements in the Database but there are only about 2000 items in the db.
Does anyone know where the performance difference is coming from?

Regards

Comment: What kind and how many allocations are happening in this startup method? If you scale the number of items in the db, does the startup time scale in the same proportion?

Answer (score 1):

How about NSLog?  Are you doing a lot of NSLogging?  There definitely is a performance difference given that Xcode is sort of monitoring the app, and able to pop you into the debugger when it crashes.  However, I had no experience with a performance hit this great.

Comment: No, there are no NSLogs. Even when I run the application with Instruments it is a lot faster then running it form XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Is it building and "installing" in the simulator?  That's the only thing I've seen that takes that much of a drastic difference in time before the program actually launches.